# Responding to “Sorry for the late reply.” statement in the email

Tags: email

I had applied for a job position, for which the interviewer replied me back after a couple of days. However, he started his email with 'Sorry for the late reply'. Now to revert him back with a response, I want to know what can I say back to the his 'Sorry for the late reply' statement. Shall I just write "No problem. (continue with main body of response)" or "It's ok. (continue with main body of response)" ?

PS: The question was originally asked at https://english.stackexchange.com/q/110616/41946. But based on the comment received there, I am asking the question here.

Comment: Not everything someone says requires a response.

Comment: Where do you live? Without cultural context, this question is very difficult to give a good answer to. My guess however is you are in Western culture (given the apology was given in the first place) - probably don't need to even address it if you don't want to.

Comment: we are based in London

Comment: @Blrfl is correct. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Just ignore the comment.  A few days (2-3) response isn't late.  If it was a month later I would still ignore it.

Comment: revert isn't really a word in this context & country.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I see that the question has been closed. I am not sure what was 'ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical' in the question. However, it seems @Kortuk understood the question correctly, and I am happy with his answer. (sorry, as I still don't have enough points, can't vote his answer up). The comments about ignoring to reply for the said sentence also seems reasonable. But I just wanted to be a bit polite, so Kortuk's answer was helpful. Regarding 'revert' not being a correct word in context-I did not know about it, thanks, I take the point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to play it safe, write something that is true with or without the statement they made apologizing but can be seen as a repose to it.

> It is great to hear back from you,

Or nicer, noting you know their time is valuable, implying you consider a delay on their part reasonable.

> I appreciate your time,

Just a few ideas, often I receive much better results from others when you answer in such a way that you don't consider them irrelevant.